# JMeter Loop Counters

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to JMeter and trying to setup a Test Plan where I need to pass variable data against each request. e.g I have 10,000 products which have sequential unique Id(PD1...PD10000). I also have the 250 prices records as well with sequential unique Ids(PR1....PR250).
I want my requests to be sent in a way that each product Id is looped 250 times against price record.
I tried to setup Threads (User) count to 250 and Loop Count 10,000 and used the standard functions $(__counter(FALSE,)} but this just get incremented and goes beyond 10,000 limit.
Could someone please advise how can I setup the two variables or loop controller so that I can pass the repeated data e.g

```
{ ProductId : ${ProductId}, 
  PriceId : ${PriceId} 
}
```

where ProductId loop between 1 - 10000 and PriceId loops between 1-250.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need each product to perform 250 iterations, then Threads (User) count should be 10000 and Loop Count should be 250. Assuming the value to be substituted is PD1, PD2 etc., Create separate counter (Config element -> Counter) for Product ID and Price ID, Reference name as product_id and price_id respectively and use as below

```
{ 
ProductId : PD${product_id}, 
PriceId : PR${price_id} 
}
```

Counter reference http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter

Else use CSV data set config and retrieve the product and price id from csv file.
Refer: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config

Comment: I tried using above but got outofmemory exception as I believe my client machine cannot create 10,000 threads.

Comment: try increasing the heap memory in jmeter.bat (windows) - By default it will be 512MB `set HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx512m` . Or else add remote generators [link] http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) would be easier to use, example configuration:

- While Controller, condition: `${__javaScript(${counter} < 250,)}`

  - [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) configured as:

    [image: Counter Configuration]
  - Your request here

See [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) article for more detailed explanation and some more While Controller use cases.

I wouldn't recommend playing with Threads (virtual users) number for controlling the number of loops, it needs to be used for **controlling the load only**, you need to design your test plan in such a way so it would execute the same scenario no matter how many virtual users are defined. For example if you have 1 virtual user it should go through all 10 000 product ID records and loop each 250 times. If you have 2 virtual users - they need to take different records so the test will finish 2x times faster, etc.